# Parou de executar quando adicionei o printf

Tags: c, windows, if, else, printf

Fiz um codigo fonte em C, condicional, porem quando eu adiciono uma função printf o windows relata que o programa parou de ser executado.
Veja o codigo:  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKTcr.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9YUf.png

OBS: EU USO O WINDOWS 7 HOME BASIC, E O MEU EDITOR E COMPILADOR É O DEVC++, SE ISSO INTERFIRIR EM ALGO ME AVISE, POR FAVOR. E SE FOR PROBLEMA DE HARDWARE, E AVISE TAMBEM

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int valor = 3;
    char resultado;

    if(valor = 1){
        resultado = 's';
    }else{
        resultado = 'n';
    }
    printf("a resposta é:%s", resultado);
}
```

Comment: Poste o código na sua pergunta. Para editar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/118452/edit

Comment: O código na pergunta deve ser o código original - não o código corrigido após as respostas - senão irá confundir leitores futuros que podem ter a mesma dúvida (além de deixar as respostas sem sentido)

Answer (score 3):

Os erros são porque você está querendo imprimir um `char` (%c) como `string`(%s) no seu printf();
E existe um possível erro no seu if, pois do jeito que está escrito vai resultar em 's' pra sempre, pois `if(valor == 1)` é uma comparação, mas `if(valor = 1)` é uma atribuição.
O código correto fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int valor = 3;
    char resultado;

    if(valor == 1){
        resultado = 's';
    }else{
        resultado = 'n';
    }
    printf("a resposta é:%c", resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema do código é que você está passando `%s`(string) no `printf` quando a variável é um `char`(%c) faça assim o `printf`:

```
printf("a resposta%c", resultado);
```